# Need help incorporating a second query into first query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the first query running as needed.  This query aggregates activity levels for Users into the corresponding BusinessIds, by week.

For reporting purposes, I needed to create a new column that captures the number of UserIds that have activity levels above 0 for each Grouped Week and BusinessId.  The second query gives me the correct values on its own (although it may have more data points than needed for after the merge), but I am having a difficult time merging this into my first query.

This is likely a pretty straight forward effort, but I have been unable to figure it out from samples in other questions.  Any help is appreciated.

```
/* First Query */
SET DATEFIRST 2;
SELECT 
     SUM(
         fua.[RisksAffected]
        +fua.[IssuesAffected]
        +fua.[ChangesAffected]) AS RIC
    ,SUM(
         fua.[ProjectsCreated]
        +fua.[ProjectsAffected]) AS Projects
    ,CASE
       WHEN SUM(fua.[ProjectsCreated]) >0 
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
          END AS ProjectCreated
   ,SUM(fua.[TimesheetsCreated]) AS Timesheets
   ,SUM(fua.[ReportsAffected]) AS Reports
   ,SUM(fua.[FilesAffected]) AS Files
   ,ud.[BusinessId]
   ,COUNT ( DISTINCT fua.UserId ) AS [UserCount] 
   ,DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]) AS [ActivityDate]   

FROM [client_projectmanager].[whs].[FactUserActivity] fua
   Left Join [client_projectmanager].[whs].[DimUserDataV2] ud
      ON
   fua.[UserId] = ud.[UserId]

GROUP BY 
   DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]),ud.[BusinessId]


/* Second Query */
SET DATEFIRST 2; 
SELECT
      count (distinct sela.UserId)
      ,sela.BusinessId
      ,DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
       fua.UserId
       ,ud.BusinessId
       ,DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]) AS [Date]
       ,SUM(
            fua.[RisksAffected]
           +fua.[IssuesAffected]
           +fua.[ChangesAffected]
           +fua.[ProjectsCreated]
           +[ProjectsAffected]) AS Acttotal

FROM [client_projectmanager].[whs].[FactUserActivity] fua 
       Left Join [client_projectmanager].[whs].[DimUserDataV2] ud
       ON
       fua.[UserId] = ud.[UserId]

GROUP BY 
        DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate])
        ,fua.[UserId]
        ,ud.BusinessId

HAVING 
        SUM(fua.[RisksAffected]
           +fua.[IssuesAffected]
           +fua.[ChangesAffected]
           +fua.[ProjectsCreated]
           +fua.[ProjectsAffected])
           >0) sela 

 GROUP BY 
        DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date)
        ,sela.BusinessId
        ORDER BY DateAdd(day, -1 * datepart(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTEs if you want to do this in one statement.

```
SET DATEFIRST 2;
WITH cte1 AS (
    /* First Query */
    SELECT  SUM(fua.[RisksAffected] + fua.[IssuesAffected] + fua.[ChangesAffected]) AS RIC,
            SUM(fua.[ProjectsCreated] + fua.[ProjectsAffected]) AS Projects,
            CASE WHEN SUM(fua.[ProjectsCreated]) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                 ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
            END AS ProjectCreated,
            SUM(fua.[TimesheetsCreated]) AS Timesheets,
            SUM(fua.[ReportsAffected]) AS Reports,
            SUM(fua.[FilesAffected]) AS Files,
            ud.[BusinessId],
            COUNT(DISTINCT fua.UserId) AS [UserCount],
            DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]) AS [ActivityDate]
    FROM    [client_projectmanager].[whs].[FactUserActivity] fua
            LEFT JOIN [client_projectmanager].[whs].[DimUserDataV2] ud ON fua.[UserId] = ud.[UserId]
    GROUP BY DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]),
            ud.[BusinessId]
),
cte2 AS (
    /* Second Query */
    SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT sela.UserId),
            sela.BusinessId,
            DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date)
    FROM    (SELECT fua.UserId,
                    ud.BusinessId,
                    DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]) AS [Date],
                    SUM(fua.[RisksAffected] + fua.[IssuesAffected] + fua.[ChangesAffected] + fua.[ProjectsCreated] + [ProjectsAffected]) AS Acttotal
             FROM   [client_projectmanager].[whs].[FactUserActivity] fua
                    LEFT JOIN [client_projectmanager].[whs].[DimUserDataV2] ud ON fua.[UserId] = ud.[UserId]
             GROUP BY DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,fua.[QueryDate]),fua.[QueryDate]),
                    fua.[UserId],
                    ud.BusinessId
             HAVING SUM(fua.[RisksAffected] + fua.[IssuesAffected] + fua.[ChangesAffected] + fua.[ProjectsCreated] + fua.[ProjectsAffected]) > 0
            ) sela
    GROUP BY DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date),
            sela.BusinessId
    ORDER BY DATEADD(day,-1 * DATEPART(dw,sela.[Date]),sela.Date)
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte1
        -- USE INNER JOIN IF YOU WANT ONLY RECORDS THAT EXIST IN BOTH
        LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte1.BusinessId = cte2.BusinessId
                     AND cte1.ActivityDate = cte2.GroupedByDateName
```

your second query is missing column aliases.. assuming you're joining the 2 queries by BusinessId and the Date you're grouping by, you need to add column aliases

Comment: I have updated my code as suggested, and it seems to work.  Thank you for that!   I am open to other methods, if more efficient.   SQL is not my main focus, so I am learning quite a bit on this one.  As I have some null values, I used CASE to return 0 for null values.